# Javascript: How to print objects in Jrunscript?

Tags: javascript, object

Jrunscript has a `'print'` function. Yet it does not print anything useful about objects. For example:

```
js> var obj = {one:1, two:2}
```

When evaluating object `Jrunscript` outputs just that:

```
js> obj  

[object Object]
```

And `'print'` is no good as well:

```
js> print(obj)

[object Object]js>
```

What `Jrunscript` functions can be used to print object structure?

Comment: Try console.log(obj), maybe it exists. If what you want is just a javascript interpreter though, take a look at node (or rhino if you want JVM) instead.

Comment: console.log(obj) - doesn't exist in Jrunscript. What are object printing functions in Node.js and Rhino?

Comment: For Node.js `console.log` works fine.

Comment: Yes, Node.js console.log works fine.

Comment: Just tried Rhino. Interesting - Rhino also can't print objects in a meaningful way ((

Answer (score 2):

use rhino+env.js:

http://www.envjs.com/

sample:

```
load('env.rhino.1.2.js');
var t1 = {// 10
    "1" : {
        "q0" : "q1",
    },
    "0" : {
        "q1" : "q2"
    }
};
print(JSON.stringify(t1));
```

Of course you get other useful stuff, but it helps you for the moment